# Core Data NSPredicate NSDate filtering just for time

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject in Coredata with a NSDate property.

These NSDate contain different Days and Times,

I'd like to filter with NSPredicate but just by time, for example something like any day from 9:00 to 11:00.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use predicateWithBlock:
Core Data supports this method in the in-memory and atomic stores, but not in the SQLite-based store. If you use the SQLite-based store, fetch all objects and then filter.

Comment: Thanks, yep, finally I used the second option, because my database is SQLite-based. Thanks